# Why doesn't Vue run/update a computed property with a reference to this inside a filter function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a select box connected to a Vue computed property. I'm wondering why one of my `computed` property attempts works and the other doesn't.

```
<select>
<option v-for="option in filteredItems">{{option.description}}</option>
</select>
```

`filteredItems` is a computed property. This code works:

```
vInstance = new Vue({
    ...

    computed: {
       filteredItems: function(){
           let someID = this.filterID;
           return this.allItems.filter(function(item){
               return item.id === someID;
           })
       }
   }
})
```

This version does not

```
computed: {
    filteredItems: function(){
        return this.allItems.filter(function(item){
            return item.id === this.filterID;
        })
    }
}
```

The two functions are almost identical, other than that the first version sets `this.filterID` to a different varaible to be used in the filter. Why does that work, and the other doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing related with Vue itself. It's how `this` works in JS. In the second code block, `this` will probably the `window` and therefore `this.filterID` will be undefined. However in the first code example, `this` will be Vue instance therefore `this.filterID` will be defined. Take a look at [this link](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/) to read more about `this` scope in JS.

Comment: The behavior OP is describing is a little related to Vue. Computed properties set implicit watchers on any reactive data used in the function. The value of the computed property will update whenever any of the dependant properties update. So, the computed property in the second example isn't updating when the Vue instance's `filterID` changes, because it doesn't have a real reference to it, so Vue isn't watching it for changes.

Comment: Great answers, I didn't realize `this` was different inside the `filter` function. Changing the filter to use an arrow function fixes it, as `this` still references the Vue object with the arrow function.